# Can you explicitly exclude some classes when making a shared library?

Tags: c++, linker, g++, shared-libraries

Suppose I have a static library called `Vehicles.a`, in which it has a virtual base class `Vehicle`, and many classes derived from `Vehicle`, like `Car`, `Truck`, `Van`, `SUV`, all these classes have virtual member functions which are overrides of member functions of base class. Now I have a object file `Client.o`, in which there is `std::vector<*Vehicle>`, now i am trying to build a shared library from this `Client.o` by linking to `Vehicles.a`, but i know for some specific clients to whom the final shared library is shipped, they will never use class `SUV`, how can i exclude `SUV` from the shared library during linking stage? Since I want the shared library to only include what is necessary.

Btw, the shared library is built using g++.

Comment: What OS? I’ve done this kind of thing on Mac using the visibility attribute.

Comment: How are the unwanted classes currently pulled into the link?

Comment: Have every class in its separate cpp file, and just don't tell the linker/archiver to include the unwanted object files.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano, it's on Linux. Visibility attribute controls the symbols' visibility, i am afraid the code is still there.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, I think it's due to the vector of the virtual base class, `Client.o` doesn't know which derived class will be used, so the linker is pulling everyone.

Comment: The dependency for a virtual base class goes into the other direction, so it has to be something else.  Try linking with `-Wl,--cref` to get an idea of the actual dependencies.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, i am using `g++` command to make the shared library, seems `g++` doesn't support `--cref`. Not sure if there is similar flag for `g++`

Comment: @Allanqunzi, I wrote `-Wl,--cref`, not `--cref`. The `-Wl,` prefix causes the flag to be passed to the linker (it's a linker flag).

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, thank you very much. It works. It's strange that a space is not allowed between `-Wl` and `--cref`

Comment: The question offers no evidence that a shared library is being linked that
contains definitions that are not referenced in the shared library, and
as far the scene-setting takes us, it would not be expected to happen. [mcve] needed.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i exclude SUV from the shared library during linking stage?

That should *already* be happening.

If you end up with `SUV` inside of your shared library, *something* in `Client.o` is causing it to be pulled in (possibly indirectly).

Examining link map with `g++ ... -Wl,-Map` or symbol cross-reference with `g++ ... -Wl,--cref` should answer what that something is.

Alternatively, remove `SUV.o` from `Vehicle.a`, relink your shared library, and check what symbols are now missing:

```
# First make sure the library is linked with all required symbols:
g++ -shared -o ... Client.o Vehicle.a -Wl,--no-undefined

# Now remove SUV.o from Vehicle.a
ar d Vehicle.a SUV.o

# This should now fail, and tell you which object requires SUV.o
g++ -shared -o ... Client.o Vehicle.a -Wl,--no-undefined
```